# query a query in VBA

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

Hi guys I dont know if this makes sense but how can I query another query in VBA?

I will show with example below

This is my first query

```
strSQL1 = "SELECT DISTINCT SourceBank" _
    & ", Fullname, FirstNames" _
    & ", Surname, Company" _
    & ", EmailAddress" _
    & " FROM question" _
    & " WHERE FirstNames = '" & strFirstNames & "'" _
    Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

Then I want to do something like this. Query the first query

```
        strSQL2 = "S"SELECT * from " & strSQL1
    Set rs1 = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

I just want to know if this is possible and if not then what is the best way around it?
All I want to do is to be able to query another query/string/recordset.

thanks

Comment: why do you use tag [mysql]? ms-access use Jet SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it almost like you've wrote:

```
strSQL2="SELECT * FROM (" & strSQL1 & ")"
```

but be sure not to include ; in strSQL1

upd, try:

```
strSQL2 = "SELECT Question.EmailAddress, SUBQUERY.EmailAddress &" _ 
          & "FROM Question LEFT JOIN (" & strSQL1 & ") AS SUBQUERY ON Question.EmailAddress = SUBQUERY.EmailAddress"
```

OR just save sql1 into QueryDef (Query in ms access) and use it like source table.

Comment: and how is it used in a query with a left join?  
 
<code> strSQL1 = "SELECT Question.EmailAddress, (" & strSQL & ").EmailAddress &" _ & "FROM Question LEFT JOIN (" & strSQL & ") ON Question.EmailAddress = (" & strSQL & ").EmailAddress" </code>

Comment: hmm. I'm only getting back 1 record count when I should be getting a lot more

Comment: i changed the join type but still get the same count

Comment: left join was to select all Question and some connected rows from subquery. what result do you need?

Comment: Left join is what I want. I want all records from question and only matching records from strSQL1 where the email matches. It's just that I'm not getting the 18k records I should be getting. I'm only getting one from this - RsCount = rs1.RecordCount

Comment: 1. have you done rs1.movelast and rs1.movefirst before checking RecordCount ?  2. update question with current code

Comment: Aha. move last, move first seems to have done the trick. many thanks